# jQuery: Regex to validate US postal doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, frontend

With the code below, nothing seems to work. No alert message when I type non-numeric values in the Zipcode field. Please help me identify the issue.

```js
$("input:text[name='address_1[zip]']").keyup(function(e) {
  var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
  if (String.fromCharCode(charCode).match(/^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/)) {
    console.log("Please enter a number for zip code");
    $("input[name='address_1[zip]']").val("");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="address_1[zip]" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is about to only accept 5 digits for US ZIP <s>and i have no idea about the rest of grouping regex : `(?:[-\s]\d{4})` , it is not related to what you need.</s>
and i corrected the code for you :

```
jQuery("input:text[name='address_1[zip]']").keyup(function(e) {
    //var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode    
    // no needed!
    if (!$(this).val().match(/^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/)) {
        alert("Please enter a number for zip code");
        jQuery("input[name='address_1[zip]']").val("");
        return false;                        
    }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks John, does your code cover all US zip codes?

Comment: I did't change the regex part , if you have copied the regex for US Zip , so it will work then

Comment: Something is wrong with the regex, when I type number, it alerts saying Please enter a number for zip code

Comment: because the event is set to keyup , everytime user writes , the event calls , and if number length is < 5 , user will recieve error , maybe its a good idea to change the event for `.change()`

Comment: Thanks, it is working. But the focus goes away with the change in case of wrong zip. How to get the focus to remain with the same input in case of wron entry?

Comment: what do you mean by focus ? the input removes!? its caused by this line : 
`$("input[name='address_1[zip]']").val("");` , comment it and check if everything is good.

Comment: I meant that the cursor moves to the next field after the alert. I want it to remain in the same zipcode textbox for the user to renter the correct ZIP

Comment: i think it is caused by `alert`

Comment: John, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked

Answer (score 2):

This works - we need the timeout

```js
const re = /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/;
$("input:text[name='address_1[zip]']").on("blur", function(e) { 
  const $this = $(this);
  if (this.value && !re.test(this.value)) setTimeout(function() { $this.val(""); $this.focus() },100);
});
```

```css
.red { border: 1px solid red  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="address_1[zip]" /><input type="text" name="city" />
```

Comment: Yes, it does work. But it doesn't accept 57401 - 57402 as a valid US zip code? Could you please get me the perfect regex that validates all US zip code

Comment: @PKTG Please see update

Comment: It isn't considering 57401 - 57402 as a valid ZIP. I checked it myself

Comment: Hi, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked